# Scrollable Contents

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrollable

I am able to use this jquery function     `.scrollable();`       to scroll contents from right to left. However I will like the content to scroll from left to right. here is my code

===================For the HTML=====================

```
<div id="Ticker" >
    <ul class="items">

    <li class="item">content 1</li>

   <li class="item">content 2</li>


   <li class="item">content 3</li>
   <li class="item">content 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

======================For Javascripts========================

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">

    $(function() {  

var api= $("#Ticker").scrollable({horizontal:true, speed:2000}).autoscroll({ autoplay:true});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the autoscroll properties, try setting the direction:

```js
{autoplay: true, direction: right}
```

Comment: I have tried both none work                                              $("#Ticker").scrollable({horizontal:true, speed:2000,direction: 'right'})                                                    {autoplay: true, direction: right}